# Testing React Drag and Drop using Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am having trouble simulating and testing the drag and drop in Enzyme. Here is my code (I removed some handle functions). I have included the test code that I tried but `handleDragIn` function is not getting called. What am i doing wrong?

```js
export default function DragAndDrop(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [drag, setDrag] = React.useState(false);
    const dropRef = useRef(null);

    const handleDrag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    const handleDragIn = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        dragCounter++
        if (e.dataTransfer.items && e.dataTransfer.items.length > 0) {
            setDrag(true);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let div = dropRef.current;

        // initiate the event handler
        div.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragIn);
        div.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragOut);
        div.addEventListener('dragover', handleDrag);
        div.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop); 

        return function cleanup() {
            div.removeEventListener('dragenter', handleDragIn);
            div.removeEventListener('dragleave', handleDragOut);
            div.removeEventListener('dragover', handleDrag);
            div.removeEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
        };
    });

    return (
        <div data-test="dropRef" ref={dropRef}>
            {drag && 
            <div className={classes.sub1}>
                <div className={classes.sub2}>
                <div data-test="upload-component">Upload</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my test code:

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import DragAndDrop from './DragAndDrop';

const findByTestAttr = (wrapper, val) => {
    return wrapper.find(`[data-test="${val}"]`);
}

const mockProps = { handleDrop: jest.fn() };

it('allows the user to drag a file', () => {
    const component = shallow(<DragAndDrop { ...mockProps }/>);
    const dropRef = findByTestAttr(component, 'dropRef');
    dropRef.simulate('dragenter')
    expect(handleDragIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: `handleDrag` nor `handleDragIn` are functions passed as props in your component so I wouldn't expect the mock functions in the test to be called unless the component under test is passed and invokes them.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, I forgot to change that part of the code. I tried using props and without it. It didn't work. I have updated the code.